# scipy mannwhitneyu with nan values

Tags: python, scipy

Playing with `scipy` I noticed that the `mannwhitneyu` function uses the `nan` values to perform the statistical analysis.

Furthermore, this function does not have have a built-in option to omit these values (the equivalent function in `R` omits Na values).

What it the point of allowing such behaviour.

Example:

```
import scipy as sp
sp.stats.mannwhitneyu(x = [nan, nan, nan, nan],
                      y = [nan, nan, nan, 2],
                      alternative='two-sided')
```

That operation yields:

```
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=4.0, pvalue=0.312321421676216)
```

To properly used the function one should use `.dropna()`.

Is there anything that I'm missing that sustains this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`mannwhitneyu` has supported `nan_policy` since SciPy 1.8.0. The default behavior is `nan_policy='propagate'`:

```py
from scipy import stats
from numpy import nan
x = [nan, 2, 4, nan]
y = [nan, 1, nan, 2]
stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y)
# MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

`'omit'` and `'raise'` are also supported.

```py
stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y, nan_policy='omit')
# MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=3.5, pvalue=0.4142161782425252)

stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y, nan_policy='raise')
# ValueError: The input contains nan values
```